# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'authorization')

Tags: node.js, authentication, verification

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'authorization')
at verifyToken (file:///C:/Users/awan7/Downloads/JWT-AUTH/backend/midleware/VerifiedToken.js:4:35)

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const verifyToken = (res, req, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];
    if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401);
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
        req.email = decoded.email;
        next();
    })
}
```

i did't know what is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const verifyToken = (res, req, next) => { --->> i change my code from this

export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => { <<---  in to this

    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];
    if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401);
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
        req.email = decoded.email;
        next();
    })
}
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solved the problem.

Comment: He has changed the place of res and req.